# HTML table with different number of cells in each row: how to space the cells evenly in their row?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have an HTML table where the number of columns may differ from one row to another. Nonetheless, I would like the columns to be evenly spaced in their row. (For instance, if my first row contains 2 columns, each column should have 50% of the total width of the table; if the second row has 3 columns, each of them should have ~33% of the total width of the table.)

Moreover, I would like the table to have the width of the container (so probably with a `width: 100%`in the CSS; but the problem is that this property tells the table to split the columns evenly based on what is in the forst row only). The container width may vary, this is why I have to use percentages.

I also tried to make my table myself with divs and by specifying the width of each "cell-div" with a percentage, but this solution doesn't provide a good result on every browser: sometimes, when there is no more space on the line, the last "cell-div" of a row goes under it. (I have to specify some weird width such as `49.99998%` or `33.333233%` because I need some space for my borders as well.)

Comment: Thanks to all of you, all the solutions work but it is important not to forget to add `table-layout: fixed;` in the CSS to have the cells **really** distributed evenly.

Comment: By definition, all the rows of a table have the same number of columns. (A cell may span several columns.) Markup that violates this should not be expected to produce consistent or reasonable results. What you really have is a rather vaguely described layout issue.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you're not really using the `table` element to display tabular data, just for some alignment. One way to get the result that you want is to make each row its own table and just set a width.  Each row will evenly distribute the cells across the table width. You might need to add some more CSS formatting to get it to behave just the way you want.

You can see this at http://jsfiddle.net/RxSe5/1/.

Comment: +1 Without multiple tables or some sort of grid that is evenly divisible by all the cell number variations (so you could use `colspan`) what the OP is proposing really isn't possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can add tables inside each of the TD:

```
    <table style="width:100%;text-align:center;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table style="width:100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table style="width:100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
​
```

Or you can just add new tables:

```
<div>
    <table style="width:100%;text-align:center;">
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table style="width:100%;text-align:center;">
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table style="width:100%;text-align:center;">
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>​
```

Answer (score 0):

you could totally nest tables, you could also use tables for layout. or you could use markup how it's supposed to be used and enjoy all the fruits of its labors (accessibility, semantics, usability, etc.) just by doing the right thing. you can can change column with via colspan="" attribute on you td elements. http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/td.html